# Is it possible to have a C code deployed that passes through and overwrites keystrokes from the keyboard?

Tags: c++, linux, keyboard, x11

I use some "user friendly" programs that demand me to type in long sequences of shortcuts and other characters at times. I found some tools like cnee but nothing that could help me to automate these sequences with no time and effort. I have simply added the source code into one of these programs (Qt), but another has many dependencies so it would take time to build it.

Being also interested in Linux development, I came up with the idea to write a modified version of the keyboard driver that would allow to define and invoke the macros by using a single dedicated key. Apart from automating my keystrokes that may or may not make a big business model, this would also be a good self-learning project for Linux driver programming.

How difficult would be to implement the simple keyboard driver under Linux, such that GUI environments like Gnome would understand it? It is OK to rebuild the kernel or have some commands under root rights to load this driver when needed.

Alternatively it could be a hook somewhere above the driver, but in general the lower, the better.

Comment: This should be doable by generating fake KeyPress and KeyRelease events and sending them to the currently active window (GetInputFocus()).

Comment: Qt framework has never been a Linux keyboard driver. I have adapted to my needs some Qt applications by changing shortcuts in they source code and rebuilding them but not all applications are easy enough to build from the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to write the whole driver.
You need only C, `uinput` and some time to develop.
What to do:
0. Finding your keyboard device node. you can use evtest or detect it dynamically. You can skip it if you know keyboard's event device node path (like /dev/input/event5).

1. `open` keyboard by path.
2. grab device to prevent leak to Xorg/Wayland compositor
3. create `uinput` device with the same specifications.
4. Use `poll` to get keyboard's raw input and hook key events.